# Can I use the `Win32::GUI` to create a system tray icon for my command prompt Perl program?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that is running an infinite loop. I'd like to be able to minimize this to the system tray. Can I use the `Win32::GUI` to create a system tray icon that when maximized shows the command prompt and the output of the script?

Edit: My perl script is a process by itself. Its running continuously. How can I run the systray icon a sanother process?

Comment: http://lmctfy.org/win32%20tray

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

```
use Win32::GUI();

my $main = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
    -name => 'Main',
    -text => 'Perl',
    -width => 200,
    -height => 200
);

my $icon = new Win32::GUI::Icon('GUIPERL.ICO');
my $ni = $main->AddNotifyIcon(
    -name => "NI",
    -icon => $icon,
    -tip => "Hello"
);

Win32::GUI::Dialog();

sub Main_Terminate {
    return -1;
}

sub Main_Minimize {
    $main->Disable();
    $main->Hide();
    return 1;
}

sub NI_Click {
    $main->Enable();
    $main->Show();
    return 1;
}
```

Copied from:

[Win32-GUI Tutorial Part4](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GUI/docs/GUI/Tutorial/Part4.pod#System_Tray_Icons)

If you want your tray icon in a different process you can use `fork()` but then you will need some way to comunicate father and child process.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the ActiveState PerlTray component to do and it has worked well for me. Of course, it's a commercial offering though reasonably priced (in my opinion).